# Store on Google Shopping, Adwords and Merchant

Tags: shopify, google-ads-api, google-shopping

I'm working on a store (shopify). I want to show my products on google shopping.
I have a feed on Merchant, connected with adwords. I setup a campaign with everything is needed.

The problem is, my store and my products, in categories like I have on store and adwords campaign, not showing the products or the store.

I don't have any ideas, I read all documention of google about it, and the problem continuous.

PS: If is possible, I wanna try add my articles on the showcase on google search (ex.: search by "Smartwatchs")

Comment: Can you please describe your issue in detail? If the campaign is set up correctly, the ads should start showing up.

Comment: Hi, I think it is. I do everything like other campaigns I created before. My products on mechant is "green" on shopping and display. I have the products on adwords.

Comment: and the problem is that they are not showing up in google ads? Have you checked the impressions data if there are any impressions? If possible, please share a screenshot of your adwords account.

Comment: I dont understand? what is the problem. Sorry I cant share the image :\

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem. You are not able to see the products you uploaded on merchant center in your adwords?

Comment: I agree with the earlier comment to check impressions. If there are impressions, you're probably doing something wrong while checking if they are showed or not. I'd suggest to contact Google for further assistance as this is not a development issue and a Google account manager is able to check all sorts of stuff that we're not able to check for you.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I saw the products on both. Just because that I can't understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This may we way too late, but maybe it helps someone.

You said that your categories, as you have them in your store, weren't showing in Google Shopping.

I'd recommend:
A - making sure that you have assigned product types to your products in accordance with your store categories/sections (i.e. Clothing > Men's Clothing > Shirts)
B - clicking the "plus" icon to "subdivide" your product groups based on the product types you assigned.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On2Ux.png)